# With Twilio can I use custom fields in a rest request to send message?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am looking for a custom reference key to use with my application via the Twilio SMS API. To crosscheck my request, I need a reference number generated at my end to send in a rest request and get the same in response.

Is there any way Twilio allows custom parameter in the request?

Comment: What is it you need this for?

Comment: as mentioned.. to cross-check and later status update. somehow we want our own unique key, not the one generated by twilio

Comment: I'm afraid you can't add custom parameters in Twilio. Out of interest, what is wrong with saving the unique id that comes with a message sent with Twilio? Could you not tie the two keys together in your system and look up details on messages using the Twilio part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately you cannot add custom parameters in Twilio.**

You are correct in that the only way you would be able to do this is add the parameters to the querystring and we would just pass those parameters along to your application. May be in future release they will come up with custom parameters feature.

Comment: i hv tht solution already, bt looking for something allowed and in-flow